# Как вывести картинку из папки?

Tags: php, массивы

На сайте есть папка с картинками 20 шт., как вывести из этой папки изображение в echo один раз по очереди с 1 по 20. А также проверить, изображение уже выводилось и не менялось после перезагрузки страницы.

**page.php**

```
<?php
    $dir = "images/";
    $images = scandir($dir);
    $i = rand(2, sizeof($images)-1);  
?>

    <img src="images/<?php echo $images[$i]; ?>" alt="" />
```

**page-2.php**

```
<?php include('inc/page.php'); ?>
<img src="images/<?php echo $images[$i]; ?>" alt="" />
```

**page-3.php**

```
<?php include('inc/page.php'); ?>
<img src="images/<?php echo $images[$i]; ?>" alt="" />
```

...

**page-20.php**

```
<?php include('inc/page.php'); ?>
<img src="images/<?php echo $images[$i]; ?>" alt="" />
```

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к решению задач. Приведите пример вашей реализации, добавьте описание конкретных проблем, с которыми вы столкнулись.

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб передавать информацию между страницами пользуйтесь **[сессиями.](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.session.php)**

**Решение:**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $dir = "images/";
    $scanned_directory = scandir($dir);
    $images = array_values(array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.')));

    if(!$images)
    {
        echo 'Папка с картинками пуста !';
        exit;
    }

    //  Создаём счетчик для хранения ключей массива выбранных картинок,
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cnt']))
        $_SESSION['cnt'] = 0;
    else
        $_SESSION['cnt'] ++ ;

    //Оригинальный массив
    $original_images = array_slice($images, 0, count($images));

    // Выбирает срез массива со следующей позиции выбранной картинки.
    $images = array_slice($images, $_SESSION['cnt'] -1, count($images));

    // Если переменная пуста значит больше нечего выбирать, сбрасываем счетчик в начало,
    // и выбираем уже из оригинального массива.
    if(!$images)
    {
        $_SESSION['cnt'] = 0;
        $images = $original_images;
    }

    // Перемешивает уже новый массив.
    shuffle($images);

    // в выводе можно увидеть как выводится измененный массив.
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($images);
?>
<img src="images/<?php echo $images[0]; ?>" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = "images";
$images = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));
foreach($images as $key => $value ){
    echo "<img src='images/". $value ."'/><br/>";
}
```

Данный код будет выводить по алфавиту все картинки на Вашем сайте, которые находятся в папке images.

Comment: @Viher В страницах с **page-2.php** по **page-20.php** уберите строчку `<img src="images/<?php echo $images[$i]; ?>" alt="" />`. Соответственно мой код вставьте в **page.php**

Comment: Странный код, выводит на каждой странице списком все картинки.

Comment: @Viher Вы пишите развернуто в чем ваша проблема, ответ будет соответственно по теме, а так у вас не понятно, что нужно.

Comment: На сайте есть 20 страниц, и 20 картинок в папке. Нужно на каждой странице отобразить картинку из папки, и проверить что картинка уже вывелась. Если страниц будет больше чем 20, начать цикл заново. По другому не объясню, надо только рисовать...